# how to set scala Implicit value in java code?

Tags: java, scala, spark-graphx

i have a scala class with below definition:

```
object EigenvectorCentrality extends VertexMeasure[Double]{
  override def compute[VD:ClassTag, ED:ClassTag](graph: Graph[VD, ED],vertexMeasureConfiguration: VertexMeasureConfiguration[VD,ED])(implicit num:Numeric[ED]): Graph[Double, ED] = computeEigenvector(graph,vertexMeasureConfiguration)

}
```

now i want to call compute function of this class from Java Code, But i dont know that how to set Latest Parameter of compute function(Numeric[ED])  .
i call this function as below:

```
EigenVectorCentrality.compute(mygraph,mygraph.vertices.vdtag,mygraph.vertices.vdtag,Numeric.Int)
```

but get this error:
`Could not find Implicit value for parameter num : Numeric[ED]`

this class is relate to Spark Graphx. do you know that how set Implicit variable of scala in java?

Comment: compute function is taking just 3 parameter. Then, why are you passing 4 parameter to your function?

Comment: latest parameter is for implicit num:Numeric[ED].

Comment: You are passing `mygraph.vertices.vdtag` 2 times. Why?

Comment: when call a scala function in java code, parameter of functions is changed

Comment: The parameter count somehow does not add up to me. You are passing evidence for VD, but where are you passing evidence for ED? I would expect: `EigenVectorCentrality.compute(graph, vertexMeasureConfiguration, vdEvidence, edEvidence, numericEvidence)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is `ED`? You should pass the same object Scala is selecting when doing implicit resolution. Assuming `ED` is `Double`, you should pass `DoubleIsFractional` object, which is written as `DoubleIsFractional$.MODULE$` in Java.

`EigenVectorCentrality.compute(mygraph,mygraph.vertices.vdtag,mygraph.vertices.vdtag,DoubleIsFractional$.MODULE$)`

If `ED` is `Int`, it should be `IntIsIntegral$.MODULE$` instead.

If `ED` is a primitive type, there is additional trouble of mapping Scala / Java primitive types. Assuming `ED` is `int` (ie. `Int` in Scala), you cannot have a value of type `Numeric<int>` in Java, only `Numeric<Integer>`, but such implicit is not defined by default in Scala.

Comment: Thanks @Suma. That's Worked